# Adding StackOverflow answers to my Careers 2.0 profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I cannot add any links to answers that I have provided on StackOverflow. I realize that my StackOveflow rating is not over 200 and so my ranking will not show but I thought I could add my answers in at least.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed your account manually, and we believe we've found the source of this bug so it shouldn't happen again once the fix goes out.

Comment: Thanks David. I appreciate it. I edited my profile and I now see my StackOverflow rating. However, when I add an answer it appears correctly but there is no Save button so the answer does not stay on my profile. Perhaps the bug release will fix this too?